# How to convert txt file into list of integers

Tags: python, attributes

First, I have my txt file data here as:

```
51
2
2
49
15
2
1
14
```

I would like to convert them into a list to do further calculation, however I couldn't do it and I try to print it one by one by using for loop. Then the error message "Attributes error" kept showing up.

```
def main():
    file = str(input("Please enter the full name of the desired file(with extension) at the prompt below: \n"))
    print (get_value(file))

def get_value(file):

    file_open = open(file,"r")
    print (file_open.read())
    a = len(file)
    print ("Length =",a)
    for line in range file_open:
        print (line)

main()
```

Comment: You have some logic errors (e.g. `len(file)`, which is the length of the filename) and syntax errors (e.g. `range file_open`) in your code. I recommend brushing up with the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def main():
    file = str(input("Please enter the full name of the desired file(with extension) at the prompt below: \n"))
    print (get_value(file))

def get_value(file):

    file_open = open(file,"r")
    lsLines = file_open.readlines()
    lsLines = [int(x) for x in lsLines if len(x.strip()) > 0]
    file_open.close()

    return lsLines

main()
```

Comment: return "None" by this algorithm

Comment: lsLines will contain the lines read from file. Do you expect this code to reside in a function ?

Comment: It's alright, but when I print it the return shows "['51\n', '2\n', '2\n', '49\n', '15\n', '2\n', '1\n', '14']", which I don't want the "\n" in my list.

Comment: Modified the code as per your requirement. Now check it.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: wrong language.

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    ints = [int(line) in f.readlines()]
```